# how to iterate for loop in efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
for index, i in df.iterrows():
    temp=df.loc[df['security_code']==df['security_code'][index]]
```

this loop is to map dataframe  which has same security code it results in data of similar security code with different dates

> above for loop iterates each row in dataframe  and dataframe consist of 27,000 rows which takes hours to iterate all the rows

**problem is iteration through dataframe which contains huge number of rows takes lot of time and will this loop result in infinte loop?**

Comment: please read [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: After you read it, please include a sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC there is no need to use for loop to get rows with index matching 'security_code' column:

```py
temp = df[df['security_code'] == df.index]
```

Your current code will actually overwrite  `temp` as many time as there are indexes in your DataFrame.

Comment: ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Comment: i get value error as two csv files are different sizes

Comment: I edited my answer. You want to get the dataframe having equal index and security_code right ?

Comment: yes, i had to map security_code of different dates in same csv

Comment: Could you explain with more details what is the result you want to achieve ?

Comment: i want to loop 20,000 rows  within minimum possible time

Comment: But for WHAT result ? Please make a sentence explaining what your code was supposed to do.